# Permutation of rows with repetition

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, terminology

A binary matrix with exactly one entry of 1 in each row and 0s elsewhere performs a "permutation with repetition" of the rows of the matrix it left-multiplies. Example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there a technical term for such a transformation or such a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix is one the elementary operations matrices. These are: switching two rows (or columns) with a matrix like yours (which is actually a composition of one or more switches), multiplying a row (or a column) by a scalar and making linear combinations of rows.
http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/elemop/elemop.html
It is usually done among matrices but you did it on a vector.